# How can I change the Calendar Offset?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, timezone-offset, java.util.calendar

I need to change Calendar timezone offset

I tried many thing;

```
1-

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(rawOffset, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + 
System.currentTimeMillis());

2-

TimeZone timezone = new SimpleTimeZone();
timezone.setRawOffset(rawOffset);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(timezone);
```

Our API returning +1.0 timezone (Berlin) But I can't change Calender timezone offset. How can change?

Comment: “Our API returning +1.0 timezone (Berlin)” — as a `double`??

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

Don’t mingle with raw offsets. Java knows the offset for Berlin better than you. And consider not using `Calendar`. That class has a number of design problems and is considered long outdated.

```
    ZonedDateTime zdtBerlin = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
    System.out.println("Zeit in Berlin: " + zdtBerlin);
```

When I ran this snippet just now, I got this output:

> Zeit in Berlin: 2019-02-08T19:23:00.275+01:00[Europe/Berlin]

As the name says, a `ZonedDateTime` has a time zone in it. In this case Europe/Berlin. It’s the modern replacement for `GregorianCalendar` (the most common concrete subclass of the abstract `Calendar` class).

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### What went wrong in your code?

Snippet 1-: You are setting the `Calendar`’s time to an hour into the future. You are not setting the time zone.

Snippet 2-: First `SimpleTimeZone` hasn’t got a no-arg constructor, so `new SimpleTimeZone()` won’t work. Next, its `setRawOffset` expects an offset in milliseconds. If `rawOffset` is 1, you are setting an offset of 1 millisecond.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.